# Explanation of "sed" in a shell command

Tags: sed

I used the following command to extract the first "result" from multiple files and write them in a file.

```
for file in *.xml; do cat $file | grep result | sed -n 2p | sed s:"<result>":"": | sed s:"</result>":"": >> tmp.txt; done
```

I am looking at it after 2 years and I can't remember how I picked up the number in first "result"(0.018300606384717713) from 2 of them (the second one is -0.083118623723832552 )from files which look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<fit_results>
  <input_file>/Users/hunululu/Desktop/current/m203/ratios/tmp.xml</input_file>
  <time>Fri Oct 17 17:45:51 2014</time>
  <fit_converged>true</fit_converged>
  <iterations>3</iterations>
  <dof>1</dof>
  <chi_sqr_per_dof>0.088802954844880599</chi_sqr_per_dof>
  <Q>0.76570450204332174</Q>
  <parameter_values>
    <parameter>
      <name>a</name>
      <result>0.018300606384717713</result>
      <error>0.0090474462765945517</error>
    </parameter>
    <parameter>
      <name>b</name>
      <result>-0.083118623723832552</result>
      <error>0.045747262135131625</error>
    </parameter>
  </parameter_values>
</fit_results>
```

Can anybody please help me to understand how it picks up the first one instead of the second result? Thanks.

Comment: Do yourself a favor and comment the code! I just had this conversation with a co-worker.  Comment for the next guy, which could very well be yourself after you've forgotten what you did before.  Funny this came up right after.  :-)

Comment: Yes, I should. Thanks for your suggestion

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key here is `2p`. `p` stands for printing the current pattern space. But if you prepend it with some number `i`, it means print the `i'th` line in the pattern space.

In your case, the pattern space after `grep` is:

```
<fit_results>
      <result>0.018300606384717713</result>
      <result>-0.083118623723832552</result>
</fit_results>
```

Hence, `2p` picks up the second line in this, and hence the first result.

Answer (score 2):

The more fundamental issue is that any time you write a loop in shell just to manipulate text you have the wrong approach. Your whole command line can be reduced to just:

```
awk -F'[<>]' 'FNR==1{cnt=0} /result/&&(++cnt==2){print $3}' *.xml > tmp.txt
```

Comment: Best answer! On the other hand I would say it is a task for `xmllint`

Comment: Thanks a lot. This really helps to understand better